# How to Dynamically Set the “kafka_num_consumers” Value When Creating a Kafka Engine Table in ClickHouse?

Tags: clickhouse

I am trying to create a Kafka Engine table in ClickHouse and I’ve come across the `kafka_num_consumers` setting. I was wondering if it’s possible to dynamically assign a value to this setting during table creation, instead of using a fixed constant?

I have tried  ["Query Parameters"](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/syntax#defining-and-using-query-parameters), but it seems that it cannot be used in `CREATE` statement.

```sql
ClickHouse :) SET param_kafka_consumers = 1;
ClickHouse :) CREATE TABLE my_kafka_table
          (
            id UInt32
          ) ENGINE = Kafka() 
          SETTINGS
            kafka_broker_list = '127.0.0.1:9092',
            kafka_topic_list = 'my_topic', 
            kafka_group_name = 'clickhouse',
            kafka_format = 'JSONEachRow',
            kafka_num_consumers = {param_kafka_consumers:UInt32};

Syntax error: failed at position 239 ('param_kafka_consumers') (line 10, col 26):

CREATE TABLE my_kafka_table
(
  id UInt32
) ENGINE = Kafka() 
SETTINGS
  kafka_broker_list = '127.0.0.1:9092',
  kafka_topic_list = 'my_topic', 
  kafka_group_name = 'clickhouse',
  kafka_format = 'JSONEachRow',
  kafka_num_consumers = {param_kafka_consumers:UInt32};

Expected one of: token, ClosingCurlyBrace, string literal, end of query
```